# Importing a XML file in MS Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, import

I'm trying to create a XSLT file (XML transformation file) to import this XML in MS Access, can anyone help me?

I don't know stylesheet, 
I tried to create one but it doesn't show me the `QUOTATION NUMBER` and `DATE` values in each imported table as I need...

<<<< NEW XML FILE >>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BRAND_QUOTES xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:brand="http://brand" RECEIVER_ID="0000112233" SENDER_ID="888800000008">
  <QUOTATION NUMBER="1919999999" DATE="20170208" TREATMENT="Back Margin" DIRECT_BACK_REBATE_APPLY="TRUE">
    <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="SOLD_TO">
      <ID TYPE="GLN">0000119379</ID>
      <CONTACT_DETAILS>
        <NAME>TDC SPA</NAME>
        <STREET>R. PERSATTE</STREET>
        <COUNTRY>FR</COUNTRY>
        <POSTCODE>25687</POSTCODE>
        <PHONE>002996644</PHONE>
      </CONTACT_DETAILS>
    </PARTY_DETAILS>
    <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="INDIRECT_CUSTOMER">
      <CONTACT_DETAILS>
        <NAME>JEANPIERRE PORRET</NAME>
        <VAT>FR00256893364</VAT>
      </CONTACT_DETAILS>
    </PARTY_DETAILS>
    <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="SALES_EMPLOYEE">
      <CONTACT_DETAILS>
        <NAME>Marta Rossi</NAME>
      </CONTACT_DETAILS>
    </PARTY_DETAILS>
    <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="FINAL_CUSTOMER">
      <CONTACT_DETAILS>
        <NAME>CRISTIANO MOHAMED</NAME>
      </CONTACT_DETAILS>
    </PARTY_DETAILS>
    <DATE TYPE="VALID_FROM">20161103</DATE>
    <DATE TYPE="VALID_TO">20201231</DATE>
    <LEGAL_TEXTS>
      <TEXT TYPE="FIXED_TEXT1">Faisant suite à notre dernier entretien,nous avons le plaisir de vous transmettre ci-dessous nos conditions pour cette affaire</TEXT>
      <TEXT TYPE="AUTO_TEXT">Le chiffre d'affaire réalisé sur cette cotation ne sera pas intégrédans  la base de calcul des bonus contractuels.</TEXT>
      <TEXT TYPE="FIXED_TEXT2">Cette offre est valable dans la limite des stocks disponibles et sous réserve de modification de prix de notre part, aux Conditions deréglements contractuelles, Nous vous prions d'identifier vos commandesavec la mention "Affaires Spéciales" en reportant le numéro decotation et le code marché et de joindre les justificatifs descommandes clients ,Nous souhaitons que ces conditions vous permettentde donner une suite favorable à cette affaire, Dans l'attente , nousvous prions de croire en l'assurance de notre considérationdistinguée.</TEXT>
      <TEXT TYPE="HEADER_TEXT" />
    </LEGAL_TEXTS>
    <LINE_ITEMS>
      <ITEM>
        <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="BRAND">C11CD47301</PRODUCT_CODE>
        <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="EAN">8715946552071</PRODUCT_CODE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Tablet 20"</DESCRIPTION>
        <QUANTITY TYPE="MINQTY" UNIT="PCE">20.0000000000</QUANTITY>
        <QUANTITY TYPE="MAXQTY" UNIT="PCE">20.0000000000</QUANTITY>
        <QUANTITY TYPE="MINORDQTY" UNIT="PCE">0</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE TYPE="DIRECT">300.0000</PRICE>
        <PRICE TYPE="INDIRECT" />
        <PRICE TYPE="FINAL" />
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <CATEGORY TYPE="1">0B</CATEGORY>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="BRAND">F11J115142AB</PRODUCT_CODE>
        <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="EAN">8715555111333</PRODUCT_CODE>
        <DESCRIPTION>EMP-7773 VIDEOPROJECTOR</DESCRIPTION>
        <QUANTITY TYPE="MINQTY" UNIT="PCE">10.0000000000</QUANTITY>
        <QUANTITY TYPE="MAXQTY" UNIT="PCE">10.0000000000</QUANTITY>
        <QUANTITY TYPE="MINORDQTY" UNIT="PCE">0</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE TYPE="DIRECT">1500.0000</PRICE>
        <PRICE TYPE="INDIRECT" />
        <PRICE TYPE="FINAL" />
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <CATEGORY TYPE="1">51</CATEGORY>
      </ITEM>
    </LINE_ITEMS>
  </QUOTATION>
</BRAND_QUOTES>
```

**XML** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BRAND_QUOTES xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:brand="http://brand" RECEIVER_ID="0000208712" SENDER_ID="1113214000020">
    <QUOTATION NUMBER="7001234567" DATE="20161025">
        <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="SOLD_TO">
            <ID TYPE="GLN">0000208712</ID>
            <CONTACT_DETAILS>
                <NAME>CONCORD S.R.L.</NAME>
                <STREET>VIA GIGLI, 14</STREET>
                <COUNTRY>IT</COUNTRY>
                <POSTCODE>00118</POSTCODE>
                <PHONE>06/12345678</PHONE>
            </CONTACT_DETAILS>
        </PARTY_DETAILS>
        <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="INDIRECT_CUSTOMER">
            <CONTACT_DETAILS>
                <NAME>FOX SRL</NAME>
                <VAT>IT01477465457</VAT>
            </CONTACT_DETAILS>
        </PARTY_DETAILS>
        <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="SALES_EMPLOYEE">
            <CONTACT_DETAILS>
                <NAME>Mario Rossi</NAME>
            </CONTACT_DETAILS>
        </PARTY_DETAILS>
        <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="CONTACT_PERSON">
            <CONTACT_DETAILS>
                <NAME>UFFICIO BID</NAME>
            </CONTACT_DETAILS>
        </PARTY_DETAILS>
        <PARTY_DETAILS ROLE="FINAL_CUSTOMER">
            <CONTACT_DETAILS>
                <NAME>WAST SPA</NAME>
            </CONTACT_DETAILS>
        </PARTY_DETAILS>
        <DATE TYPE="VALID_FROM">20161011</DATE>
        <DATE TYPE="VALID_TO">20170331</DATE>
        <LEGAL_TEXTS>
            <TEXT TYPE="FIXED_TEXT1">Faisant suite à notre dernier entretien,nous avons le plaisir de vous transmettre ci-dessous nos conditions pour cette affaire</TEXT>
            <TEXT TYPE="AUTO_TEXT">Le chiffre d'affaire réalisé sur cette cotation ne sera pas intégrédans  la base de calcul des bonus contractuels.</TEXT>
            <TEXT TYPE="FIXED_TEXT2">Cette offre est valable dans la limite des stocks disponibles et sous réserve de modification de prix de notre part, aux Conditions deréglements contractuelles, Nous vous prions d'identifier vos commandesavec la mention "Affaires Spéciales" en reportant le numéro decotation et le code marché et de joindre les justificatifs descommandes clients ,Nous souhaitons que ces conditions vous permettentde donner une suite favorable à cette affaire, Dans l'attente , nousvous prions de croire en l'assurance de notre considérationdistinguée.</TEXT>
            <TEXT TYPE="HEADER_TEXT"/>
        </LEGAL_TEXTS>
        <LINE_ITEMS>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="BRAND">V13H010L60</PRODUCT_CODE>
                <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="EAN">8715946478609</PRODUCT_CODE>
                <DESCRIPTION>Lampe EB-93/95/96W/905/420/425W</DESCRIPTION>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MINQTY" UNIT="PCE">90.0000000000</QUANTITY>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MAXQTY" UNIT="PCE">90.0000000000</QUANTITY>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MINORDQTY" UNIT="PCE">0</QUANTITY>
                <PRICE TYPE="DIRECT">120.5000</PRICE>
                <PRICE TYPE="INDIRECT">130.0000</PRICE>
                <PRICE TYPE="FINAL"/>
                <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="BRAND">V13H010L78</PRODUCT_CODE>
                <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="EAN">8715946531045</PRODUCT_CODE>
                <DESCRIPTION>Lampe EB-SXW03/SXW18/X24</DESCRIPTION>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MINQTY" UNIT="PCE">70.0000000000</QUANTITY>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MAXQTY" UNIT="PCE">70.0000000000</QUANTITY>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MINORDQTY" UNIT="PCE">0</QUANTITY>
                <PRICE TYPE="DIRECT">85.6600</PRICE>
                <PRICE TYPE="INDIRECT">92.0000</PRICE>
                <PRICE TYPE="FINAL"/>
                <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="BRAND">V13H010L88</PRODUCT_CODE>
                <PRODUCT_CODE TYPE="EAN">8715946546049</PRODUCT_CODE>
                <DESCRIPTION>Lampe EB-9xxH/SX27/W29</DESCRIPTION>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MINQTY" UNIT="PCE">50.0000000000</QUANTITY>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MAXQTY" UNIT="PCE">50.0000000000</QUANTITY>
                <QUANTITY TYPE="MINORDQTY" UNIT="PCE">0</QUANTITY>
                <PRICE TYPE="DIRECT">78.6000</PRICE>
                <PRICE TYPE="INDIRECT">82.0000</PRICE>
                <PRICE TYPE="FINAL"/>
                <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
            </ITEM>
        </LINE_ITEMS>
    </QUOTATION>
</BRAND_QUOTES>
```

**XSLT** file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="QUOTATION/@NUMBER">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT_DETAILS">
        <CONTACT_DETAILS>
            <QUOTATION><xsl:value-of select="../../QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/></QUOTATION>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </CONTACT_DETAILS>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <ITEM>
            <QUOTATION><xsl:value-of select="../../QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/></QUOTATION>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ITEM>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LEGAL_TEXTS">
        <LEGAL_TEXTS>
            <QUOTATION><xsl:value-of select="../../QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/></QUOTATION>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </LEGAL_TEXTS>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="PARTY_DETAILS">
        <PARTY_DETAILS>
            <QUOTATION><xsl:value-of select="../../QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/></QUOTATION>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </PARTY_DETAILS>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the desired output that you are looking for? Please edit the question to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using MS Access, most likely you require normalized database tables with a shared ID here being `QUOTATION NUMBER` and `DATE`. Consider the following XSLT, using `ancestor::*` to map the above two nodes to each descendant.

Additionally, since MS Access' XML import facility is element-centric and ignores any attributes, I converted attributes to elements in the XSLT templates. Finally, since XML maintains repeating child items `TEXT, PRODUCT_CODE, QUANTITY, PRICE` that align to databases' one-to-many table relationship, I incorporated a final template to map those in separate tables:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QUOTATION">
    <xsl:copy>          
      <QUOTATION><xsl:value-of select="@NUMBER"/></QUOTATION>
      <DATE><xsl:value-of select="@DATE"/></DATE>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PARTY_DETAILS|LEGAL_TEXTS">
    <xsl:copy>
      <QUOTATION>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/>
      </QUOTATION>
      <DATE><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@DATE"/></DATE>
      <xsl:if test="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(@*)}"><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='TEXT' and local-name()!='CONTACT_DETAILS'
                            and local-name()!='PRODUCT_CODE'
                            and local-name()!='QUANTITY' and local-name()!='PRICE']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTACT_DETAILS|TEXT|PRODUCT_CODE|QUANTITY|PRICE"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CONTACT_DETAILS">
    <xsl:copy>
      <QUOTATION>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/>
      </QUOTATION>
      <DATE><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@DATE"/></DATE>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='VAT']"/>
      <VAT><xsl:value-of select="VAT"/></VAT>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TEXT">
    <xsl:copy>
      <QUOTATION>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/>
      </QUOTATION>
      <DATE><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@DATE"/></DATE>
      <xsl:if test="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(@*)}"><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
      <VALUE><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 255)"/></VALUE>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM">
    <xsl:copy>
      <QUOTATION>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@NUMBER"/>
      </QUOTATION>
      <DATE><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BRAND_QUOTES/QUOTATION/@DATE"/></DATE>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:if test="@*">
          <xsl:element name="{@*}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>        
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(@*)]"/>    
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Access VBA** *(Using MSXML, more W3C compliant than built-in TransformXML)*

```vb
Public Sub TransformXMLs()
    ' VBA REFERENCE: MSXML, v6.0
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Source.xml"
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Stylesheet.xsl"

    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Access Tables**

[image: DB XML Import]

Comment: Just a note: I got this error table:
XML Text Error Message 
TEXT table, row 3, column VALUE Truncated field

Comment: MS Access text fields max to 255 characters, so possibly you have a very long `TEXT` value. Try using xslt's [substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256054(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically in last template for *VALUE* node: `select=substring(., 1, 255)`. This will truncate the long XML node value.

Comment: Where do I have to put select=substring(., 1, 255)? thank you very much!

Comment: I just told you: in last template of the XSLT. Replace the `select` statement in `<xsl:value-of>` inside `<VALUE>` node.

Comment: I tried to modify the fourth last row of the XSLT as follow:

<VALUE><xsl:value-of select=substring(., 1, 255)/></VALUE>

but the error persists...

Comment: Can you check XML file for a very long TEXT string? Try 254 or even 250.

Comment: Any luck? Your posted example does not err out with this solution, so it must be data-specific and it's not the XML transformaiton but the Access import to tables.

Comment: But there's a problem, there's no article code (type BRAND value) reference on tables ITEM, QUANTITY and PRICE... how can I do?

Comment: That is migrated in `PRODUCT_CODE` table because of its one-to-many linkage since there are two types (one of which is *BRAND*). All tables are linked by `QUOTATION` number.

Comment: In this manner I can't go up to the price of any product, because multiple products have the same quotation...

Comment: The text truncated field is over 500 characters.

Comment: Your XML does not clearly show how the multiple nodes (items, product code, quanity, prices) correspond to each other. Which ones go with which?

Comment: Sorry Parfait, I've updated a new XML in the place of the other one, wich contains 3 different Product Codes... thanks for any help!

Comment: See updated XSLT where all `<Item>` children and attributes and values import as fields in `ITEM` table (no repeating tags). See screenshots. And `substring()` indeed does work. No error comes up with this code and posted XML.

Comment: And where is VAT info in XML?

Comment: It's at row 17, under FOX SRL:
<VAT>IT01477465457</VAT>

Comment: See update with modification of the *COMPANY_DETAILS* template, explicitly adding a `<VAT>` node.

Comment: Thank you very very very much Parfait! God bless you!

Comment: Excuse-me.... There are two more fields in the xml file, but if I add them in XSLT nothing is imported... why? Can anyone help me?
row 3 become:
<QUOTATION NUMBER="7001234567" DATE="20161025"> TREATMENT="Back Margin" DIRECT_BACK_REBATE_APPLY="TRUE">

Comment: That is not valid XML. What element is *Treatment* and *Direct_Rebate_Apply* residing in or are they in *Quotation*?

Comment: Dear Parfait, I edited the post with the new xml file, it seems there's some other change in the structure, can you help me? thanks

Comment: Just add to Quotation template: `<TREATMENT><xsl:value-of select="@TREATMENT"/></TREATMENT>` and same for other attribute. Do remember XSLT like XML is case sensitive.

Comment: It's what I've done:
<xsl:template match="QUOTATION">
    <xsl:copy>          
      <QUOTATION><xsl:value-of select="@NUMBER"/></QUOTATION>
      <DATE><xsl:value-of select="@DATE"/></DATE>
 <TREATMENT><xsl:value-of select="@TREATMENT"/></TREATMENT>
 <DIRECT_BACK_REBATE_APPLY><xsl:value-of select="@DIRECT_BACK_REBATE_APPLY"/></DIRECT_BACK_REBATE_APPLY>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

But they've changed something else in the file struct. I posted as new, because if I add this 2 new information in an old file it's imported, but the new not.

Comment: With a manual import in access, with xslt file I get this error:
Transformation error: The name cannot begin with character "1": -->1<--

Comment: I found they've added this new tag after every article:
<CATEGORY TYPE="1">0B</CATEGORY>