# Transforming Yahoo Finance Currency XML in order to import into Access with XSLT

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

I am trying to create  an XSLT file that I can use to properly import the Yahoo all currency feed at http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format.
I want to eventually build this into VBA to automatically import.

The **xml** file looks like below (but has many more currencies):

```
<list version="1.0">
<meta>
    <type>resource-list</type>
</meta>
<resources start="0" count="174">
    <resource classname="Quote">
        <field name="name">USD/KRW</field>
        <field name="price">1174.170044</field>
        <field name="symbol">KRW=X</field>
        <field name="ts">1484857724</field>
        <field name="type">currency</field>
        <field name="utctime">2017-01-19T20:28:44+0000</field>
        <field name="volume">0</field>
    </resource><resource classname="Quote">
        <field name="name">SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY</field>
        <field name="price">0.053778</field>
        <field name="symbol">XAG=X</field>
        <field name="ts">1484857681</field>
        <field name="type">currency</field>
        <field name="utctime">2017-01-19T20:28:01+0000</field>
        <field name="volume">36</field>
    </resource></resources>
</list>
<!-- iapi4.finance.bf1.yahoo.com Thu Jan 19 15:30:54 EST 2017 -->
```

I have tried creating a XSLT file but I think it is completely wrong. I have looked at some different examples but I could not figure out how to customize for the provided file. I do believe a lot of users would be interested in using this file and that it could be re-purposed for many different people.

Comment: I think at the moment it's not clear what you are asking. First of all, you should include your XSLT file. After that, which examples have you looked at (if they are relevant)? What is the expected output of the XSLT transformation? (a .csv file? a different XML format? ...)

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly stealing from Parfait's excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291698/2144390), I came up with the XSLT file

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="meta">
    <!-- omit -->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="resource">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:element name="{@*}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that will transform the source XML file to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<resources start="0" count="174">
    <resource>
        <name>USD/KRW</name>
        <price>1174.170044</price>
        <symbol>KRW=X</symbol>
        <ts>1484857724</ts>
        <type>currency</type>
        <utctime>2017-01-19T20:28:44+0000</utctime>
        <volume>0</volume>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <name>SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY</name>
        <price>0.053778</price>
        <symbol>XAG=X</symbol>
        <ts>1484857681</ts>
        <type>currency</type>
        <utctime>2017-01-19T20:28:01+0000</utctime>
        <volume>36</volume>
    </resource>
</resources>
<!-- iapi4.finance.bf1.yahoo.com Thu Jan 19 15:30:54 EST 2017 -->
```

which Access can import into a table named [resource].

Comment: Haha...no shame here! We should note that Access' import method is element-centric and not attribute-centric as this XML shows with column names.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly - Thanks Gord and Thompson

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the Macro Recorder and go to Data > From Web > Import the link you posted above.  I just did that and got the code below.

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
        "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format", _
        ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")
End Sub
```

Here is the final result.

[image]